# Problem to launch GraphDB 9.5 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphdb

I have tried to install GraphDB standalone server(9.4 and 9.5) on Ubuntu 20.04 while unzipping the zip file. Then, I went to graphdb/bin to execute "graphdb". On both version, I got the message warning below and the GraphDB server never run at localhost:7200. Il seems to have problem with Sprint framwork...?
Any ideas how to by pass this problem?
My java version is :

```
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thank you in advance for your advice.

````
/graphdb-free-9.5.0/bin$ sudo ./graphdb
./graphdb: line 75: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:43,598 [main | c.o.g.Config] Using 'file:/usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0/conf/logback.xml' as logback'hdb
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:44,388 [main | c.o.g.s.GraphDB] Starting GraphDB in workbench mode.
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:56,822 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Home directory: /usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:56,822 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Config directory: /usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0/conf
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:56,822 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Data directory: /usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0/data
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:56,822 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Work directory: /usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0/work
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:03:56,823 [main | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Logs directory: /usr/local/graphdb-free-9.5.0/logs
[INFO ] 2021-01-11 13:04:03,652 [main | c.o.g.s.GraphDB] Started GraphDB in workbench mode at port 7200.
[WARN ] 2021-01-11 13:05:24,330 [http-nio-7200-exec-1 | o.s.w.s.PageNotFound] No handler found for GET /
[WARN ] 2021-01-11 13:05:24,332 [http-nio-7200-exec-1 | o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you locale is misconfigured. Could you send the output of "locale" command? GraphDB is using LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8, so if it fails to set them it could fail to initialize. Whay you could do is chech for typo in ~/.bashrc or the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/locale

LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```